# Convert discovered bluetooth device rssi value to dBm

Tags: android, qt, bluetooth

I am working on [Qt/QML](https://www.qt.io/) application, deployed mainly on [Android](https://www.android.com/), which among other things includes Bluetooth devices discovery, which works fine. For every discovered device, I also read its signal strength (its [RSSI value](https://blog.bluetooth.com/proximity-and-rssi)) via [QBluetoothDeviceInfo::rssi()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdeviceinfo.html#rssi) method and it is always reporting **negative integer numbers**. The documentaion of [QBluetoothDeviceInfo::rssi()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdeviceinfo.html#rssi) method is very stingy and what *unit* is this number reported in and how do I convert this value to *dBm* unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units are dBm.  A negative number from -20 dBm to -100 dBm is a typical reception value.